# Setting up output directory of TestNG eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, testng, surefire

I'd like to use both testNG eclipse plugin and maven surefire plugin together. And I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129626/maven-and-unit-testing-combining-maven-surefire-plugin-and-testng-eclipse-plug/5130385#5130385), that I can listen to the output folder `"target/surefire-reports"` when running maven test and the testNG plugin view takes the data and displays the results.

But the view doesn't do anything after my "maven test" ends. And after I apply the testNG settings with "output folder", this error appears in eclipse error view

[image]

Anyway the output directory is really set to `target/surefire-reports` but the testNG view doesn't react on changes in that directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just pushed a new version of the Eclipse plug-in which should fix the problem you're seeing.